# Marked Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, poisson-process

We have $k$ distinct light switches, so let's label them $0$ up to $k-1$. Suppose they are all off initially.

At random time intervals we are simply switching one of the light switches on and off again. We choose the particular switch uniformly at random.

Let $N_t$ denote the total number of times we have done this up to time $t$, and note that $t$ is a continuous time variable.

We further suppose that $\{N_t \}_{t \geq 0}$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$.

Here's my question:

> Given we have chosen switch $0$ twice up to time $t$, find the probability that we have $\textbf{only}$ chosen switch $0$ up to time $t$.

I have tried to use the thinning of a Poisson process theorem, but seem to arrive at the concluson that it is not relevant how many times we have chosen switch $0$. But this doesn't make sense, since if we have not chosen switch $0$, then the probability is necessarily $0$, but if we have then the probability must be positive.

Comment: Well, it is given that switch $0$ is chosen twice... How is it possible that you haven't chosen switch 0 under this condition?

Comment: I am not following: you are considering the case when you have chosen switch 0 twice (so what is this talk about not choosing switch 0 at all?) and you wonder if you never chose any other switch until then. Seems like asking for $P(N_t=2\mid N_t\geqslant2, S_1=S_2=0)$ where $(S_n)$ is the sequence of switches chosen. Surely you can continue?

Comment: yeah I'm just saying that it matters how many times we have chosen switch 0. And @Did maybe, but I don't know how to work with that...

Comment: How do I continue from there?

Comment: Actually wait, pretty sure that's not what I'm after, since we are not conditioning on having chosen 0 consecutively at the beginning of our process.

Comment: We are merely conditioning on having chosen switch 0 twice up to time $t$

Comment: So, compute $$P(N_t=2\mid N^0_t=2)=P(N^0_t=2,N^1_t=N^2_t=\cdots=N^{k-1}_t=0)/P(N_t^0=2)$$ which is easy since $(N^i_t)_{0\leqslant i\leqslant k-1}$ is i.i.d.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66382/discussion-between-brock-and-did).

Comment: Your computation is correct; thinning tells that the probability of the event does not depend on the knowledge of how many numbers switch 0 is turned up. Just imagine an analogous situation, where there are $k$ different bells (labelled from $0$ to $k-1$) ringing according to its own Poisson clock, and you are only listening how many times bell $0$ is rang between time $0$ and $t$. This tells nothing about how many times other bells rang, so the event that all other bells did not ring is independent of how in detail you know about ringings of bell 0.